# Prove that $\Phi$ is not onto and $\Phi^{-1}$ is continuous (Structure Theorem for Distributions)

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, topological-vector-spaces

I'm reading the following Theorem from Trèves book:

> **Theorem 24.4** Let $T$ be a distribution of order $\leq m <+\infty$ in $\Omega$, and let $S \subset \Omega$ be its support. Given any open neighbourhood $U$ of $S$ in $\Omega$, there is a family of Radon measures $\{\mu_p\}$ $(p \in\mathbb{N}^{n}, |p|\leq m)$ in $\Omega$ such that $T=\sum_{|p|\leq m}(\partial/\partial x)^p\mu_p$, and such that $\operatorname{supp} {\mu_p} \subset U$ for every $p \in \mathbb{N}^{n}$, $|p|\leq m$.

However, I got stuck in the first lines of the proof. He says:

> *Proof:* Let $N=N(m,n)$ be the number of $n-$uples $p=(p_1,...,p_n)$ such that $|p|\leq m$. For simplicity, let us set $E_m=C_c^m(\Omega)$. There is a natural injection of $E_m$ into the product space $(E_0)^M$: it is the mapping which assigns to each $\phi \in E_m$ the set $((\partial/\partial x)^p \phi)_{(p\in \mathbb{N}^{n}, |p|\leq m}$ of its derivatives of order $\leq m$. **This mapping is obviously linear, obviously  *not* onto. But it is an isomorphism into for the structures if TVS, as immediately seen ($\phi_n$ converges to zero in $E_m$ if and only if every one of its derivatives of order $\leq m$ converges to zero in $E_0$).**

The map above mentioned is given by
$$\Psi:C_c^m(\Omega) \to [C_c^o(\Omega)]^N$$
given by
$$\Psi(\phi)=((\partial/\partial x)^p \phi)_{p \in A},$$
where $A=\{p \in \mathbb{N}: |p|\leq m\}$ and $\# A=N$. I was able to verify linearity and injectivity. However, I was unable to justify that it is not onto continuous and $\Phi^{-1}:\operatorname{Im}(\Phi) \subset [ C_c^0(\Omega)]^{N} \to C_c^m(\Omega)$ is continuous where $\operatorname{Im}(\Phi)$ is endowed with the topology induced by $[ C_c^0(\Omega)]^{N}$.

In addition, the justification for continuity is not clear because these spaces are not metrizable (they are $LF$-spaces). The continuity of $\Phi$ I believe is valid, because if $K$ is a compact subset of $\Omega$ it is enough to prove that $\Phi|_{C_c^m(K)}:C_c^m(K) \to [C_c^0(\Omega)]^N$ is continuous. Since $\Phi$ is linear, $C_c^m(K)$ is metrizable, if $\phi_n \rightarrow 0$ in $C_c^m(K)$ then every of its derivatives of order $\leq m$ converges to zero in $C_c^0(K) \hookrightarrow C_c^0(\Omega)$. Therefore, $((\partial/\partial x)^p\phi_n(x))_{p \in A} \rightarrow 0$ in $[C_c^0(\Omega)]^N$. (Is that correct?)

> **My question:** How to prove that $\Phi$ is not onto and $\Phi^{-1}$ is continuous?

Comment: Minor point: The map is surjective if $m = 0$, then it's the identity of $E_0$. The continuity assertion is in my opinion only obvious if one knows a neighbourhood basis of $0$ in these spaces, or knows by other means that the image (a closed subspace of $(E_0)^N$) is the strict inductive limit of the corresponding spaces. Do you know a neighbourhood basis of $0$ in $\mathscr{C}_c^m(\Omega)$?

Comment: I saw in John Horváth's book that a fundamental system of neighborhood of $0$ in $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ is given by $V(\{m_k\},\{\varepsilon_k\})=\{ f \in C_c^\infty(\Omega):\sup_{|\alpha|\leq m_k} \sup_{x \in \Omega \cap \complement K_{k-1}} |(\partial/\partial x)^pf(x)|\leq \varepsilon_k\}$, where $m_1<m_2<\cdots \rightarrow \infty$  and $\varepsilon_1> \varepsilon_2>\cdots\rightarrow 0$.  Could I say that a fundamental system of neighborhood of $0$ in $C_c^m(\Omega)$ is given by ...

Comment: $U_m(\{\varepsilon_k\})=\{ f \in C_c^m(\Omega):\sup_{|\alpha|\leq m} \sup_{x \in \Omega \cap \complement K_{k-1}} |(\partial/\partial x)^pf(x)|\leq \varepsilon_k\}$ with $\varepsilon_1> \varepsilon_2>\cdots\rightarrow 0$? With respect to the second part, I don't know if I understood correctly, it would be more or less this: Let $E$ be an LF-space, $\{E_i\}$ $(i=0,1,\dots)$  a sequence of definition of $E$, then $G=E\times \cdots \times E$ is a LF-space with $\{E_i\times\cdots \times E_i\}$ $(i=1,2,\dots)$ being a sequence of definition of $G$. @DanielFischer

Comment: Right, the $U_m(\{\varepsilon_k\})$ form a neighbourhood basis. (Except that in the translation from Horváth's notation to Trèves' you forgot to change one $\alpha$ to $p$.) And also right that a finite product of $LF$-spaces is an $LF$-space. (Technically, if $E^{\rho}$ is an $LF$-space with sequence of definition $E^{\rho}_i$ for $1 \leqslant \rho \leqslant r$, then on $F = \prod_{\rho = 1}^{r} E^{\rho}$ the product topology coincides with the $LF$-space topology induced by the sequence of definition $F_i = \prod_{\rho = 1}^{r} E^{\rho}_i$.)

Comment: Now, in the product $(E_0)^N$ a neighbourhood basis of $0$ is given by $\bigl(U_0(\{\varepsilon_k\})\bigr)^N$, and it is immediate that $\Phi\bigl(U_m(\{\varepsilon_k\})\bigr) = \bigl(U_0(\{\varepsilon_k\})\bigr)^N \cap \operatorname{im} \Phi$, which shows that $\Phi$ is an emebedding.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you very much, now everything is clear!

Answer (score 0):

$\Phi$ cannot be onto as the other coordinates of $\Phi(\phi)$ are already determined by its coordinate for $p = 0$. For example if $y = (y_p)_{p \in A}$ is such that $y_0 = 0$ and $y_p \neq 0$ for some $p \neq 0$, then $y \in [C_c^0(\Omega)]^N \setminus \Phi(C^m_c(\Omega))$.

The spaces $C^m_c(\Omega)$ are NOT the spaces of test functions. They are even normable by the sup norm
$$||f|| = \max \{||(\partial f / \partial x)^p||_\infty; \; p \leq m \}$$
(each compactly supported function have compactly supported derrivatives).

Further, $\Phi^{-1}$ is continuous as
$$\Phi(y_n) \rightarrow \Phi(y) \text{ in } \Phi(C^m_c(\Omega)) \iff \text{ for each } p \in A : \;\;(y_n)_p \rightarrow y_p \text{ in the sup norm} \iff$$
$$\iff y_n \rightarrow y \text{ in } C^m_c(\Omega).$$

Comment: The topology in $C_c^0(\Omega)$ is NOT the sup norm, because this is a $LF$-space. The topology in $C_c^0(\Omega)$ is the inductive limit of $\{C_c^0(K_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $\{K_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ exhaustion of $\Omega$.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I am used to a different notation.
The first part of the proof should be still true. The second part could be modified to work, just instead of the "in the sup norm" take "in $C^0_c(\Omega)$" and instead of sequences take nets. Is this correct?